# JSSOR Slider: change tiled menu slider layout from 2 to 4 rows?

Tags: slider, jssor

How can I add 2 more rows to the JSSOR tiled menu slider? Thank you.

Comment: That was a bit of a chor. I did it a while back tweeking the thumbnav css values back and forth until i got them just right. And I changed it to only show image thumbs. I got 5 rows with values around 280. But sadly that solution is requiring you to use a fix height at 1000px.

Answer (score 0):

Given a slide defined as follows, you will see all content in a slide is fully customizable. To define 4 rows instead of 2 rows, you can edit css.

```
<div>
    <a class=appicon01 style="left: 0px; top: 0px; background-position:0px 0px;" href="#">
        <div class=appiconcb></div>
        <div class=appiconc>Menu Item 01</div>
    </a>
    <a class=appicon01 style="left: 160px; top: 0px; background-position:-160px 0px;" href="#">
        <div class=appiconcb></div>
        <div class=appiconc>Menu Item 02</div>
    </a>
    <a class=appicon01 style="left: 320px; top: 0px; background-position:-320px 0px;" href="#">
        <div class=appiconcb></div>
        <div class=appiconc>Menu Item 03</div>
    </a>
    <a class=appicon01 style="left: 480px; top: 0px; background-position:-480px 0px;" href="#">
        <div class=appiconcb></div>
        <div class=appiconc>Menu Item 04</div>
    </a>
    <a class=appicon01 style="left: 640px; top: 0px; background-position:-640px 0px;" href="#">
        <div class=appiconcb></div>
        <div class=appiconc>Menu Item 05</div>
    </a>

    <a class=appicon01 style="left: 0px; top: 160px; background-position:0px -160px;" href="#">
        <div class=appiconcb></div>
        <div class=appiconc>Menu Item 06</div>
    </a>
    <a class=appicon01 style="left: 160px; top: 160px; background-position:-160px -160px;" href="#">
        <div class=appiconcb></div>
        <div class=appiconc>Menu Item 07</div>
    </a>
    <a class=appicon01 style="left: 320px; top: 160px; background-position:-320px -160px;" href="#">
        <div class=appiconcb></div>
        <div class=appiconc>Menu Item 08</div>
    </a>
    <a class=appicon01 style="left: 480px; top: 160px; background-position:-480px -160px;" href="#">
        <div class=appiconcb></div>
        <div class=appiconc>Menu Item 09</div>
    </a>
    <a class=appicon01 style="left: 640px; top: 160px; background-position:-640px -160px;" href="#">
        <div class=appiconcb></div>
        <div class=appiconc>Menu Item 10</div>
    </a>
</div>
```